# Divide Fields by Sum to get Percentage SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I wanted to figure out a way to get the percentage by using the data divided by the sum of the overall data.
For example:

```
[NumberofClients]/[Sum(NumberofClients)]
```

For each row it should have a different percentage based on the number of clients.
However, when I execute the expression above I always get 100%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're apply the `Sum`, it will be calculated in the current Scope - if this expression is in a Details row, it will only ever be looking at one row, which explains why it's always 100%.

You need to use a Scope parameter to get more than the current row in the Sum, something like:

```
=Fields!NumberofClients.Value / Sum(Fields!NumberofClients.Value, "MyDataset")
```

Which is giving the % value for the particular row compared to all the rows in the Dataset, which seems to be what you're after.

You can change the Scope parameter to be a group instead of the whole Dataset as required.